# Microsoft.Expression.Interactions troubles

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight project and have started looking at behaviors. All the examples I've seen reference the assembly something like this:

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

This is after having included a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, of course. Specifically, I am looking for the PropertyChangedTrigger which is in this DLL (I believe). If I go into my XAML and type in , it tells me that it's not found and to check my assemblies.

Here's a screen shot from my project:

[image]

If that's not clear enough, a full resolution image is available [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmSpe.jpg)

It could be a version problem I suppose - the version I have is 2.0.5.0 according to Visual Studio. That said, if I type in 'ei:', I get no intellisense at all.

Have I missed something obvious here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the assembly name too in the declaration, as follows:

```
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

Comment: I have tried that, to no avail. Picture can be seen [here.](http://i.imgur.com/nsnP8.jpg). Also just typing 'ei:' doesn't prompt any Intellisense still.

Answer (score 0):

note this is the same namespace even for WPF in 4.5 framework (i.e. didnt change to 2011 or  2012)

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

(for the new preview version of Blend)